# Query String - Multiple parameters

Tags: html, query-string, window.location

I am trying to pass the following `Query String` but am being met with a `Webpage not available` error:

`window.location.href = "chaindeals.html?chainID=" + chainID + "&imageURL=" + imageURL;`

I also tried changing the `&` to `&amp;` but I'm getting the same error.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what actual URL does your concatenation of values result in? What gets actually requested by the browser (developer tools -> net panel)?

Comment: Which browser you getting this error?

Comment: Your script is fine, Can you make sure whether the filename is correct?

Comment: The variable `chainID` is `1` and `ImageURL` is `"http:\/\/www.8coupons.com\/stores\/chain\/logo\/big\/Dunkin_Donuts_1224967687.png"`. Everything seems to work fine when I only use the `chainID`...

Comment: This is a picture of the error message: http://i.imgur.com/BFzvKCr.png

Answer (score 1):

please try this.

`var url = '';
 url = url.concat('chaindeals.html?chainID=',chainID, '&imageURL=', imageURL);
 window.location.href = url;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the full url to `window.location.href`, not only the page name :

```
var host = "http://" + window.location.host;
window.location.href = 
    host 
    + "/chaindeals.html"
    + "?chainID=" + chainID 
    + "&imageURL=" + imageURL;
```